# Reading file using rememberLauncherForActivityResult not working on some devices

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to read any type of file using rememberLauncherForActivityResult in Kotlin Jetpack Compose:

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) 
{ resultUri ->
   ...
}

return Column {
    Button(onClick = {
        launcher.launch("*/*")
    }) {
        Text("Open file")
    }
}
```

This code was working ok until recently, but recently it started returning null resultUri on some devices. When changing "*/*" to "image/*" it again works fine on all devices.
How can I fix this to read any type of file?